# Flutter: How to sort the data of a table with double list

Tags: dart, flutter

I have created a **table** where I want to show data from **two different lists.**

- The **first** list is called **Players** where all the players are.
- The **second** list is called **PlayersStats** where is all the statistics of each player.

If there are **3** in the **player** list, there are **3** in the **playersStats** list.

**Problem:**

The problem I have is the time to sort the data. They have to be related, but I can't achieve it.

In the **screenshot** you can **see 3 players**.
Before ordering the data, **everything is correct.**

- RaiiLKilleR - 101 Goals
- **RaiiKonN - 30 Goals**
- Miriam - 100 Goals

But after ordering, the players get messed up.

- RaiiLKilleR - 101 Goals
- RaiiKonN - 100 Goals
- **Miriam - 30 Goals**

I hope someone can help me, I appreciate any help, thanks.

[image]

```
getRowsPlayers() {
    final rows2 = new List.generate(widget.players.length, (int index) => new DataRow(
        cells: [
          new DataCell(new Text(widget.players[index].gameID, style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black))),
          new DataCell(new Text(widget.playersStats[index].goals.toString(), style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black))),
        ]));
    return rows2;
  }

  bool isSort = true;

  Widget bodyData() => DataTable(
      onSelectAll: (b) {},
      sortColumnIndex: 1,
      sortAscending: isSort,
      columns: <DataColumn>[
        DataColumn(
          label: Text("PLAYERS"),
          numeric: false,
          onSort: (i, b) {
            print("$i $b");
            setState(() {

            });
          },
          tooltip: "To display players",
        ),
        DataColumn(
          label: Text("GOALS"),
          numeric: true,
          onSort: (i, b) {
            print("$i $b");
            setState(() {
              if(isSort){
                widget.playersStats.sort((a, b) => b.goals.compareTo(a.goals));
                widget.players.sort((a, b) => b.gameID.compareTo(a.gameID));
                isSort = false;
              } else {
                widget.playersStats.sort((a, b) => a.goals.compareTo(b.goals));
                widget.players.sort((a, b) => a.gameID.compareTo(b.gameID));
                isSort = true;
              }
            });
          },
          tooltip: "To display goals",
        ),
      ],
      rows: getRowsPlayers());


  Widget players() {
    return Container(
      child: bodyData(),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title.toUpperCase()),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: widget.themeBackground,
      ),
      body: new Container(
        child: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            widget.type == 'GLOBAL'? global()
            :
            widget.type == 'COMPETITION' ? competition()
            :
            widget.type == 'FRIENDLY' ? friendly() : players()
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is because the `PlayersStats` and `Players` are different list.

```
widget.playersStats.sort((a, b) => b.goals.compareTo(a.goals));
widget.players.sort((a, b) => b.gameID.compareTo(a.gameID));
```

PlayersStats sort by `goals`, so the result would be `[101 Goals, 100 Goals, 30 Goals]`

Players sort by `gameID`, so the result would be `[RaiiLKilleR, RaiiKonN, Miriam]`

These two list sort by itself. So the result is not you expected.
You need to combine two list into one list like

```
class Player {
    final String gameID;
    final int goals;
    Player({this.gameID, this.goals});
}
```

and call 
`widget.playersStats.sort((a, b) => b.goals.compareTo(a.goals));`

and your `getRowsPlayers` would be

```
  getRowsPlayers() {
    final rows2 = new List.generate(widget.players.length, (int index) => new DataRow(
    cells: [
      new DataCell(new Text(widget.players[index].gameID, style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black))),
      new DataCell(new Text(widget.players[index].goals.toString(), style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black))),
    ]));
    return rows2;
  }
```

Then result would be your expected.

Comment: It's true, converting it into a single list has worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First Make Objects:

```
class Data{
    final String DataName;
    Data({this.DataName});
}
```

Then Call your list in builder with Widget

```
 List<Data> myData= snapshot.data;
 myData.sort((a, b) => a.DataName.compareTo(b.DataName));
```